# Change pixels in RenderTexture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and have to use unity for a university research I am doing. For this I need to render a scene and use an external tool to modify render image data. This tool needs to read all pixels and generate a separate image based on the original data. So far following https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/NativeRenderingPlugin I was able to change a texture. However passing the render texture to the dll does nothing. Can someone please help.

This works:

```
 tex.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;

tex.Apply();


// Set texture onto our material

GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;

SetTextureFromUnity(tex.GetNativeTexturePtr(), tex.width, tex.height);
```

This does not work:

```
Camera camera = Camera.main;

var rt = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(Screen.width, Screen.height);

camera.targetTexture = rt;

camera.Render();

       

var currentRT = RenderTexture.active;

RenderTexture.active = camera.targetTexture;



camera.Render();

Texture2D image = new Texture2D(camera.targetTexture.width, camera.targetTexture.height);

image.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, camera.targetTexture.width, camera.targetTexture.height), 0, 0);

image.Apply();



RenderTexture.active = currentRT;

camera.targetTexture = null;

SetTextureFromUnity(image.GetNativeTexturePtr(), image.width, image.height);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Stuck on this for a long time.

Comment: What exactly does `does not work` mean? Have you debugged it step by step?

Comment: I was not able to step into the dll project, however using a debug callback function I can make sure the SetTextureFromUnity method in dll is called and the parameters are set as expected. However the texture modification from dll does not reflect in unity player.